# How to run a project using a C++/CLI assembly on another computer?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, visual-c++-runtime

I have a 3rd-party C++ assembly, which I need to use in my C# project. Hence I wrote a C++/CLI wrapper for the C++ assembly. Everything compiles and runs fine on my development machine.

But when I copy the content of my `bin` directory to one of our other machines, it crashes. The reason is, that it cannot load my C++/CLI-Wrapper assembly. It gives the typical message: `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyWrapperAssembly' or one of its dependencies.`

So I did some investigations: I made sure, that MyWrapperAssembly could not be found, and added an event handler to the [assembly resolve event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Within that handler I loaded MyWrapperAssembly [for reflection only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0et80c7k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I then loaded all the [referenced assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The reflection only loading of MyWrapperAssembly works. So I am sure, that the file could be found. But when I try to load it

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("hiddenDirectory\MyWrapperAssembly.dll");
```

It crashes with the above mentioned error `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyWrapperAssembly' or one of its dependencies.`

Since the reflection only load worked, I was certain that there must be something wrong in the C++ layer. I compared the installed versions of the C++ Redistributable on my development machine and on the test machine and noticed, that there are some packages missing. So I downloaded and installed these packages on the test machine:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=5555)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=14632)

And it did not work. Then I tested 6 different PCs. My programm runs on 3 PCs and crashes on the other 3. The only thing that differentiates the PCs is the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Runtime`. When it is installed, it seems to work.

But I can't find an installer for that package in the internet. So I installed Visual Studio 2013 on one PC where my programm crashed. After I installed Visual Studio (and with that the C++ Runtime), my program runs.

So I assume that I need that C++ runtime. It is no option to require Visual Studio on our customers PC. So I need to deploy the C++ runtime. But the question is:

**Where do I get the Visual C++ Runtime from?**

Or does anybody know if I am missing another thing?

Comment: You probably need the .NET framework / runtimes installed

Comment: Also check that your c++ code is compiled in Release mode.  I have had issues trying to run native C++ compiled in Debug on target machines because there are different vc runtime libraries

Comment: @OMGtechy: The .NET framework is installed.

Comment: Use dependency walker to figure out which dependencies of the C++ dll aren't found, so you know for sure which runtime is needed.

Comment: @MDK: I cannot compile the c++ code. It is a 3rd party library which is not open source.

Comment: You'll need to determine your runtime dependencies, right now you have too little insight.  You get that from paying attention to the Output window when you run your app, you see the DLLs getting loaded.  You must enable unmanaged debugging to see everything.  And you can see the list with the Debug > Windows > Modules window.  And you can get it from SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see your app searching for the DLL and not finding it.  And using a telephone to talk to the 3rd party is never going to hurt.

Comment: @stijn: I used the dependecy walker, and there are no differences in the errors and warning between the machines where it runs, and those where it crashes.

Comment: You have to use Dependency Walker in profiling mode, so it watches while the app actually runs.  It's a bit tricky with .NET programs since some of the checkboxes on the profile options will cause .NET itself to crash.  With some care, though, you can still get the information you need from it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I would be glad, if you could post an detailed answer about your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio 2013, you need the 2013 runtime, not the 2010 runtime.

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: On the machines where It runs, there is only the 2010 runtime installed. So I think, that I need at least one installed runtime.

Comment: @Rico-E no, you need the runtime matching the compiled program

Comment: @Rico-E OK if it works with the 2010 runtime installed, what's your question? You already know where it is and how to download it, just make sure it gets installed along with your program.

Comment: @DavidYaw: I did not know which package installs the runtime. That was my question. You just gave me the answer. But the microsoft site seems to be down. So I cannot test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest runtimes from here: [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003).

You'll need *at least* the one matching the VS version you used to build the C++/CLI project (so if you use VS2010 you'll need the VC++ 2010 runtime).

Then, if the C++ library you're wrapping also needs a VC++ runtime, you'll have to install that one as well. The library provider should have told you the dependencies.

Note that if you linked to a third-party `.lib` file, you should use the same VS version that they used to compile it. Otherwise you'll end up using two different runtimes simultaneously, which could cause issues. C++/CLI will have to use a manged-compatible runtime, but it's less likely to cause trouble if the versions are matched.